# Getting number of parameters in FUNCNAME

Tags: bash

Why does Snippet A

```
echo "params are ${FUNCNAME[@]}; param count is ${#FUNCNAME[@]}"
```

return

```
params are main; param count is 0
```

But Snippet B

```
_foo(){
    echo "params are ${FUNCNAME[@]}; param count is ${#FUNCNAME[@]}"
}

echo $(_foo)
```

return

```
params are _foo main; param count is 2
```

For Snippet A, shouldn't param count be `1`, instead of `0`?

Comment: Side note: `echo $(_foo)` is a useless use of `echo`. It's like `echo $(echo $(echo $(_foo)))`. Just `_foo`. (I think there was a bug with FUNCNAME but can't find the stackoverflow question where I read about it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. According to bash manual:

> This  variable  exists  only when  a  shell function is executing.

And see [Chet's comment](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-11/msg00022.html) regarding this in "bug-bash" mailing list.